# Order names based on factor

Tags: r

I want to order my column-names based on the names in a column of another data frame. I want to order the names in `isomir_Hep` based on `ClinicalDataHep$NamesClean`. Is there a way to do this simple?

```
> ClinicalDataHep$NamesClean
 [1] 1018      1065      1068      1104      1167      1196      1222      1237      1241      1302      1304     
[12] 1322      1372      1474      1532      1540      1588      1604      1743      1808      1809      1859     
[23] 1894      2218      2239      HEP014    HEP015    018       020       045       mm7       d10       s26      
[34] vs29      21        27        32        bf33      38        39        45        46        TxHEP-014 TxHEP-015
[45] TxHEP-018 080       082       084       086       088       090       091       092       094       096      
[56] 102       112       113       120       121       134       140       144       145       146       157      
[67] 158       161       164       176       185       186       192       201       204       215       236      
77 Levels: 018 020 045 080 082 084 086 088 090 091 092 094 096 1018 102 1065 1068 1104 112 113 1167 1196 120 ... vs29

> names(isomir_Hep)
 [1] "092"       "112"       "121"       "164"       "TxHEP-014" "TxHEP-018" "082"       "084"       "mm7"      
[10] "086"       "088"       "094"       "096"       "102"       "113"       "120"       "134"       "140"      
[19] "144"       "d10"       "145"       "146"       "157"       "158"       "161"       "176"       "185"      
[28] "186"       "192"       "201"       "s26"       "204"       "215"       "236"       "21"        "27"       
[37] "32"        "38"        "39"        "45"        "46"        "vs29"      "1018"      "1065"      "1068"     
[46] "1104"      "1167"      "1196"      "1222"      "1237"      "1241"      "1302"      "bf33"      "1304"     
[55] "1322"      "1372"      "1474"      "1532"      "1540"      "1588"      "1743"      "1808"      "TxHEP-015"
[64] "1809"      "1859"      "1894"      "2218"      "2239"      "104"       "HEP014"    "HEP015"    "HEP018"   
[73] "020"       "080"       "045"       "090"       "091"
```

Comment: I would suggest using `match`

Comment: Is `isomir_Hep[as.character(ClinicalDataHep$NamesClean)]` what you are looking for?

Comment: Error in `[.data.frame`(isomir_Hep, as.character(ClinicalDataHep$NamesClean)) : 
  undefined columns selected

Comment: Perhaps need an `intersect` operation if you are not going to accept the (very sensible) suggestion to use `match`.

Comment: I tried match(names(isomir_Hep), ClinicalDataHep$NamesClean)

Comment: This gives the mathcing columns, but how to I rearrange based on this match?

Comment: You could try `isomir_Hep[, as.integer(ClinicalDataHep$NamesClean)]`

Answer (score 0):

Create a new dataframe named `newClinicalDataHep` and loop through it to repopulate it with the rows ordered according to `names(isomir_Hep)`.

```
#Initialize newClinicalDataHep
newClinicalDataHep <- ClinicalDataHep[which(ClinicalDataHep$NamesClean==names(isomir_Hep)[1]),]

#Loop through to repopulate it    
for(i in 2:length(names(isomir_Hep))){
    newClinicalDataHep <- rbind(newClinicalDataHep , ClinicalDataHep[which(ClinicalDataHep$NamesClean==names(isomir_Hep)[i]),]
}
```

Comment: Error: unexpected '{' in "for(i in 2:length(names(isomir_Hep)){"

Comment: Sorry, the `for` statement had an unclosed bracket. I fixed it and it should work now.